# Yii2 GridView - Generate filtered or sorted URL

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, crud

I use `gii` generate the CRUD page of `Product`, I can access the the list by `index.php?r=product` and in code, the url is `['/product']`. Now I want to access the `product` index page with filtered parameter and sorted parameter?

Is there any tool or standard way to achieve these?

For example, there is two column `name` and `price`, I want access the page with `name` like `laptop` and sorted by `price`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer of a general nature can give you a first address. What you ask is very well-organized and managed just by the framework itself. For all these things the Yii2 provides all the elements to be used. The only problem is that all these elements are many and it takes a little time to take advantage of them.
In practice, for those who ask you,  some activities can be carried out easily by introducing oppurtune action in the controller of your classes/models, for example, in the `product controller`, you can create an  action to intercept the search by name.

```
ActionProductByName($name)
```

that will invoke a URL

```
......./web/index.php?r=product/product-by-name&name=laptop
```

In this action you can handle the code needed to return the requested data to an appropriate view

For the sorting you can act at various levels with the appropriate queries that return the data required in the desired order to a  dataProvider objects and then perform the render of these data with their view.

I hope this first answer can be useful